# C/C++ Runtime Multidimensional Dynamic Array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, runtime-error

I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct _DynamicArray {
    int *data = nullptr;
    _DynamicArray *ptr_next = nullptr;
    _DynamicArray *ptr_dim = nullptr;
} DynamicArray; // so that every matrix cell contains another matrix cell
```

And then the following recursive method:

```
void _BuildArray(std::string const& source, StringIterator& sit, DynamicArray *dArray, bool& error) {
    if (!error) {
        while (sit+1 < source.length()) {
            ++sit;
            switch (source[sit]) {
                case '[':
                    dArray->ptr_dim = new DynamicArray();
                    _BuildArray(source, sit, dArray->ptr_dim, error);
                    break;
                case ']':
                    return;
                case ',':
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    break;
                default:
                    std::string str;
                    while (std::isdigit(source[sit])) {
                        str.push_back(source[sit]);
                        ++sit;
                    }
                    --sit;
                    if (str.empty()) {
                        error = true;
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        dArray->data = new int(stoi(str));
                        dArray->ptr_next = new DynamicArray();
                        dArray = dArray->ptr_next;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then if I pass "[[1], 2, [[3,4], 5], [[[]]], [[[6]]], 7, 8, []]" as a parameter, it builds the following flatten: "[1,2,6,7,8]" (instead of "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]"). Why?

The calling snippet is this:

```
StringIterator sit = 0;
bool error = false;
this->dynArray = new DynamicArray();
_BuildArray(this->listString, sit, this->dynArray, error);
```

Comment: I don't get it, you use `std::string` and then you want to complicate life yourself with raw pointers while you have so many facilities in C++ like `std::list`, `std::vector`..

Comment: @Jack Anyway, how would you do that using std::list and std:vector (what would be the structure) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your recursive `_BuildArray` call returns, you don't advance `dArray` like you do in the `default:` case. Meaning the next `[` you encounter will overwrite the results of the previous `[`.

Comment: If I embed a trace `if (dArray->data!=nullptr) {std::cout << "OVERWRITE\n";}` before the `dArray->data = new int(stoi(str));`, it prints nothing.

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs No you've misunderstood. Say you get `[], []`in the input string. It will allocate `dArray->ptr_dim` and recurse into the function, then return at the `]`. The next `[]` does the same thing, overwriting the previous `ptr_dim`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just to clarify my comment, I was talking about a structure which utilizes C++ STL structures to avoid having to manually manage allocations and dynamic memory, something like:

```
class CellVisitor
{
public:  
  virtual accept(Cell* cell) = 0;
};

class Cell
{
public:
  virtual void visit() = 0;

};

class ContainerCell : public Cell
{
private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Cell>> cells;

public:
  void addCell(...) { ... }

  void visit(CellVisitor* visitor) override
  {
    visitor->accept(this);
    for (auto& cell : cells)
      cell->visit();
  }
};

class IntegerCell : public Cell
{
private:
  std::vector<int> data;

public:
  void visit(CellVisitor* visitor) override
  {
    visitor->accept(this);
  }
}
```